# passed both -- meaning?

Tags: word-meaning, transitivity

Source: *[US Congress passes Russia sanctions, arms for Ukraine](http://news.yahoo.com/us-congress-passes-russia-sanctions-arms-ukraine-054621335.html)*

Usage example with a context:

> Identical texts of the Ukraine Freedom Support Act **passed** both the Senate and House of Representatives on Thursday, but because of a technical issue it returned to the Senate where it **passed** by unanimous consent moments before the chamber adjourned late Saturday night.

How should I understand **passed** in this context? Does this mean that the Act went through those two legislative institutions for approval, but was sent back to where it came from? In the second instance, I don't understand how it's possible that we have the word **by** and the verb **passed** is in the passive voice, but there's no axillary verb like *is* around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand how it's possible that we have the word by and the verb passed is in the passive voice, but there's no axillary verb like is around.

The verb **passed** is used in the active voice in your excerpt.

A draft piece of legislation can indeed **be passed** by a legislative body. But it can **pass** a legislative body too, in the active-voice sense, meaning largely the same: an adoption by the majority of the voters.

Imagine [a bill passing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-eYBZFEzf8) "the gates", say, after which it's no longer a bill but a law.

That's why there's no verb "to be" that is usually employed to create Passive Voice:

> ..  Act **passed** both the Senate and House ..  **it returned** to the Senate where **it passed** by unanimous consent ..

The draft Act ("it") returned to the Senate. In the Senat, **it passed**.

Come to think of it, it does look strange without a direct object:

> The Act passed the Senate. ("the Senate" as direct object)
>    The Act passed. (no direct object)

But according to Macmillan Dictionary, the verb "to pass" can be used intransitively (without an object):

> **[pass (7)](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/pass#pass_40)** [INTRANSITIVE/TRANSITIVE] if a law, proposal, etc. passes, or passes a particular law-making body, it becomes official as the result of a vote
>   *If the bill **passes**, it will fundamentally affect people's employment rights.*

It's the words "by unanimous consent" that are confusing a little. They describe the manner in which the draft Act passed, but the (non-native) reader starts looking for the missing "*was*".

---

Related articles at Wikipedia:

- *[Ergative verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergative_verb)*
- *[Antiacusative verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticausative_verb)*
- *[Causative alteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causative_alternation)*

Answer (score 5):

**Passed** in this context is synonymous with **was approved by** in the first instance; and in the second instance **was approved** (owing to the different grammatical ordering of subject and object 'by' becomes redundant in terms of demarcating which noun is the subject of the sentence), you should be able to parse it correctly yourself, but in short:

Yes, it was initially approved by both legislatures, but was required to be resubmitted to the Senate again (owing to a 'technical issue'), this time it was approved unanimously.

The 'by' after the second 'passed' refers to the *manner* (unanimous) of it's passing, not the *instrument* (the Senate).

Answer (score 1):

Be careful. In the first instance, it says the bill was "passed" (was approved). In the second instance, it says the bill "passed by unanimous consent" In between the two, it says there was a technical error. So the events happened like this. 
1. The bill was passed (approved)
2. There was a technical error (the bill was not passed).
3. The bill was passed by unanimous consent (the bill was approved again)
4. Moments before the senate closed (phew!)

So yes, it passed.

There's no axillary very because the clauses are different.

It passed, it was passed, it has been passed, all mean the same thing. Either way, (by unanimous consent) is a separate clause that answers the question (How?) and only modifies the stand alone clause "it passed". It's a compound sentence, because who wants to write this:

The bill passed.
The bill passed by unanimous consent. 
The bill passed moments before the Senate Closed.

See spot run :D

So we substitute "It" for "the bill" and create a compound sentence out of our three clauses, to end up with "It (the bill) passed by unanimous consent moments before the Senate closed." Cool? Awesome!

Can you say "was passed"...you absolutely CAN. You can say "the bill was passed by unanimous consent" if you want to. But you don't HAVE to. That said, as a native English speaker with a degree in English I had to read the sentence three or four times before I could figure out if the bill did, or did not, pass. Therefore I can say with absolute certainty that the sentence you were given is awkward and does not convey the meaning it's trying to shape.

So in conclusion, you are absolutely right. The sentence SHOULD read "the bill WAS passed". Interestingly, a lot of government writings "write around the point" this way so that you never know which meaning is correct. For a full explanation of this writing style, read a book called "1984" (I'm being facetious of course).